# how to fix controls changing size and font size in vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I have created a form in vb.net windows forms application and gave my form a certain size and the controls a certain font size. After the design, before writing any code, I executed the program and the output is a form which has a small size than what I have designed and also a small size of controls than what I have designed. How can I fix this?

Comment: [Make your app DpiAware](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13228495/7444103) and design at 100% scale. Visual Studio issues a warning when you don't.

Comment: Thanx a lot now it's perfect